# Is it possible to preview which class files will Java compiler generate?

Tags: java, package, javac

Is there an option for `javac`, say `--dry-run`, that will instruct the compiler not to do the actual compilation, but to parse the source file(s) and list which `.class` files (including package path) will be generated?

Consider this example:

```
$ cat example.java
package whatever.example;
class First {}
class Second {}
$ javac -d . example.java
$ find .
.
./example.java
./whatever
./whatever/example
./whatever/example/First.class
./whatever/example/Second.class
```

The source file was compiled into two `.class` files and, as the `-d` option was specified, package structure was generated. I would like to know such information **before** compilation. Something like this:

```
$ javac --dry-run -d . example.java
./whatever/example/First.class
./whatever/example/Second.class
```

Alternatively, if there is no such an option for `javac`, is there any third-party utility that can do such a thing?

Comment: I don't know of any such option - but given that it would have to do quite a lot of the work anyway, why not just compile to a temporary directory?

Comment: Compiling to a temporary directory will require to "parse the results". And making the results reliable will end up in writing a specialized utility. Before doing so I would like to know what options do I have.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "parse the results" here - you'd just be walking the directory tree. How does that involve parsing?

Comment: I mean that walking the directory tree **is** parsing of the compilation results. I realize that it's a simple task, but if you try to make a self-contained utility you will probably need to do more than that. At lest to create a temporary directory for each run. Well, still simple enough :)But as I already said, I just looking for an existing solution.

Comment: That's an odd use of the word "parsing" then, IMO. Normally one parses a data stream of some description, converting it from one format into another, or into objects... I definitely wouldn't call "making calls to the `File` API" a parsing operation. Anyway, the long and the short of it is that I don't know of anything that will do this - and wouldn't expect to, as it seems a pretty niche use case.

Comment: We also needed to do this for the qbs build system. I ended up using the Java compiler APIs for this (WIP): https://codereview.qt-project.org/160346

Answer (score 2):

try

```
javac -verbose -d . javaclass.java
```

this actually lists all the actions that a compiler is working on. towards the end you can what all classes have been generated with package structure.

I have compiler via the above code. I get the below output towards the end of the list.

```
[wrote RegularFileObject[.\com\SC\JustTesting.class]]
[wrote RegularFileObject[.\com\SC\JustTestingSecond.class]]
```

There are lot of other options, just type `javac` on the command prompt to look at them.

I don't know if I one can know, prior to compiling, this information.

Comment: Great! Half problem solved. However, that will compile and write files. Any way to disable this? Of course I can, as @Jon Skeet suggested, compile to a temporary directory, but that seems to me an overkill. Maybe there is a way to do "dry run" programmatically?